# Outlook 365 Reply Text is Right-Aligned by Default

Tags: outlook, office365

I'm using Outlook in Microsoft 365 (specifically, Version 2311, Build 17029.20068 Click-to-Run). When I create a new email, the text is left-aligned. However, when I reply to an email, my reply text is right-aligned, and I need to explicitly set the text to left-aligned. This is annoying because it happens on every email. For what it's worth, I only have the Windows English language pack installed on my computer, so it's not like I have any languages that are right-to-left.

I can't seem to find default paragraph styles for replies where I might change it to be left-aligned by default. Does that exist somewhere? Did I accidentally change the default to right-aligned somehow?